# Deploying multi-module app to jboss

Tags: maven, jakarta-ee, netbeans

I have a maven project that contains several sub projects/modules(ears,wars, ejb's). Is there a way I can deploy the entire project at once, and how would I do that? My IDE is NetBeans.

Answer (score 0):

What is the jboss version that you are currently using?
I think that you can create one shell script which is charge of to deploy all your modules. I have not seen any plugin that allow to do that.